# Bootstrap 3: Open Dropdown on Hover When Another Dropdown Is Open

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, svelte

I have a couple of Bootstrap 3 (have to use it for reasons out of my control) Dropdowns within a navbar that I would like to behave like an application menu. Normally, the dropdowns open on click, but if any of the other dropdowns is currently open, they should also open on hover.

Bonus: A solution that integrates nicely with Svelte, which I use as my front-end framework.

Below is an example. Dropdown 1 should open on hover if Dropdown 2 is open, and vice versa.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap 3 Dropdowns</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown 1 <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you need to use bootstrap within a svelte project, I guess you'd better use sveltestrap rather than invevitably having to rewrite it at some point.

Comment: Thanks for the nice suggestion. I was not aware of that project. Would have been nice to know a while ago. I am afraid I am a bit too far in now to change to a new set of components. I also need a lot of customization and only Dropdown and input components, which were all rather easy to implement. So, I am not sure it's easier to learn now how to customize sveltestrap than sticking with my own components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate jQuery to your project for simple small behaviors like this and use svetle for everything else since you are too far in a project to migrate to svetlestrap...
jQuery is lightweight and can be integrated with a simple script tag in a html so I guess this is the least wrong solution

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
var isAnyDropdownOpen = false; // Track if any dropdown is open

// Modify the behavior of the dropdowns based on hover events
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(
    function() {
        // Only open on hover if another dropdown is already open
        if (isAnyDropdownOpen) {
            $('.navbar .dropdown').removeClass('open');
            $(this).addClass('open');
        }
    }, function() {
        // Optional: decide if you want to auto-close on mouseleave
    }
);

// Detect opening of any dropdown
$('.navbar .dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
    isAnyDropdownOpen = true;
});

// Detect closing of dropdowns
$('.navbar .dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
    // Check if this is the last one open before marking as none open
    if ($('.navbar .dropdown.open').length <= 1) {
        isAnyDropdownOpen = false;
    }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap 3 Dropdowns</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown 1 <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! It seems that I forgot to mention that only one dropdown should be open at any time.

Comment: so when dropdown1 is open than on hover over dropdown2 the dropdown 2 should open and 1 should close and vise versa ? @JulianKarch

Comment: Thanks for your fast reaction. Yes, you are right.

Comment: i have edited my answer so it now reflects the behaviour you are after @JulianKarch

Comment: "jQuery is lightweight", it's really not. Also, you can just do all of that without JQuery.

Comment: @brunnerh on their website they say its fast and small JavaScript library
I use it for a while and I never encountered any sort of lag when using jQuery, so there is my assumption it is lightweight. If you have some benchmarks or something please share that I might reverse my statement than. Also I never said it is not possible to do without jQuery that is just a solution I came up with and I assumed that for the asker using jQuery is more feasible than vanilla JS

Comment: E.g. the component library Preact has [4.5KB gzipped](https://pkg-size.dev/preact@10.20.0), jQuery has [31KB gzipped](https://pkg-size.dev/jquery@3.7.1), i.e. more than 6 times the size. Bundlephobia has similar numbers and puts the time difference over a slow 3G connection at [90ms](https://bundlephobia.com/package/preact@10.20.0) vs [0.59s](https://bundlephobia.com/package/jquery@3.7.1). If all you do is add a few event handler and classes, you really should not be using jQuery. (Well, I oppose all use of it anyway.)

Comment: Also, [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) is deprecated, if anything use `.on`.

Comment: @brunnerh thank you for the comparision I will look into the Preact than I have only been introduced to jQuery at work until my current job I was doing only backend

Comment: Preact was just an example for a lightweight library, it does not mean that I would recommend using it. Personally, I would go with Svelte for building frontends and for just adding a little bit of code like here I would not use any library at all.

Comment: @brunnerh: Can you post the vanilla javascript solution? Would be curious about it.

Answer (score 1):

Here would be an example of the keep-open logic without using jQuery.

But I realized that this is a fairly pointless exercise since older versions of Bootstrap have a dependency on jQuery. So unless you implement the default interaction logic yourself (which I would not recommend because it is easy to get wrong), you will have to import jQuery anyway.

```js
(() => {
  const dropdowns = [...document.querySelectorAll('.navbar .dropdown')];
  dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
    dropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
      if (dropdowns.some(d => d.classList.contains('open')))
        dropdowns.forEach(d => {
          d.classList.toggle('open', d == dropdown);
          d.querySelector('[data-toggle="dropdown"]')
            .setAttribute('aria-expanded', d == dropdown);
        });
    });
  });
})();
```

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
          role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown 1 <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action 1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
          role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```